# Need to use a function inside the map of a list

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just learning JavaScript and I'm trying to do the following. Let's say I have the following function:

```
f(a,b) {return(a+b)}
```

And now I have a list of for example the following:

```
list = [1,2,3]
```

What I would like to do is map for that list in which I call the function above `f` with a predefined value and each value of the list. I've tried this:

```
listB = list.map(x => f(x+23))
```

But it returns a `NaN`, and if I add some brackets that snippet returns `undefined`.

What's going on and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `f(x, 23)` instead of `f(x + 23)`:

```js
function f(a,b) {return(a+b)}

listA = [1,2,3]
listB = listA.map(x => f(x,23))

console.log(listB)
```

Comment: Oh, true... My bad on that, didn't even think about it. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 1):

you have error in your function call `f(x + 23)`. This is because your function `f` expects 2 arguments, and you forward only one. number + undefined -> `NaN`

Comment: Oh, that's true, I was missing a comma instead of the plus symbol. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can re-write it as

```
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const listb = list.map(f);

function f(num) {
  return num + 23;
}
```